# Is there a ranking of states based on how unitary/federalized they are?

Tags: federalism

As an example, the UK is formally considered a unitary state but in reality its subregions enjoy a lot of autonomy and are able to pass laws of their own. On the other hand Russia is formally a federation [but in practice](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8505/how-much-is-russia-actually-a-federation?rq=1) all of its states are centrally controlled from Moscow and the legal system is more or less unitary across the entire country.

Does there exist a ranking of states based on how unitary/federalized they are in practice? I suspect Vatican would be the most unitary state while Switzerland the most federalized one, but it would be interesting to see how other countries are ranked.

Comment: [This article](https://politica.elpais.com/politica/2017/10/13/actualidad/1507890167_867636.html)(Spanish) quotes [this 2016 study](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/measuring-regional-authority-9780198728870?cc=es&lang=en&) which seems a revision/enlargement (some of the authors are the same) of [this 2008 study](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13597560801979464), but a) it talks about region authonomy, not countries (the same country can have different levels of regions, like US Territories/US States/Washington D.C.) and

Comment: b) the only freely available article, the Spanish article, does not provide a full list but is centered around the Spanish ratings. And of course, I would put my money on the existence of other rankings, with similar but slightly different criteria.

Comment: @SJuan76 thanks for your input, I was able to track down the full dataset (see my answer below).

Comment: Regarding regional autonomy in the UK (and this is born out by the low ranking below), remember that British devolution is asymmetric: while, for example, the Scottish Parliament has a lot of power, for 80% of the UK population there is no comparable equivalent.

Comment: A system like the U.K. is called a "Devolved Unitary State" and the national government has the the right to alter the powers up to and including the abolishment of local governments.  Contrast with true unity states, such as France, in which there is no government other than the national government and federations like the U.S. where the national government manages a limited number of political powers that were ceded by a bunch of independent states, which only deals in those matters the member-states collectively agreed on .

Comment: It should be pointed out that Unitary vs Federalism is a question of regional administration and it should not be read that a country with more protections for local governance is "more free" or "more democratic" than a country with little to no protections for local governments.  It merely speaks to how governments manage resources among regions within their territory.

Comment: @hszmv yes, you can only derive how consistent laws are across the country. In a fully unitary state you'd have just 1 set of laws, with zero variance capacity by local authorities.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, [such an index indeed exists](https://www.arjanschakel.nl/index.php/regional-authority-index):

> The **Regional Authority Index** (RAI) measures the authority in self rule and shared rule exercised by regional governments with 96 countries on an annual basis over the period 1950-2018.

I've selected the country scores as of the year 2018 into the table below. You can find additional information about the project and individual country profiles on the [second author's website](https://garymarks.web.unc.edu/data/regional-authority-2/).

| Country | RAI (2018) |
| --- | --- |
| Germany | 37.67 |
| Bosnia and Herzegovina | 36.34 |
| India | 35.60 |
| Spain | 35.60 |
| Belgium | 33.88 |
| United States | 29.61 |
| Pakistan | 28.67 |
| Canada | 27.77 |
| Switzerland | 26.50 |
| Italy | 25.95 |
| Australia | 25.45 |
| Argentina | 24.50 |
| Austria | 23.00 |
| Peru | 22.06 |
| Russian Federation | 21.86 |
| France | 21.85 |
| Brazil | 21.79 |
| Malaysia | 21.48 |
| Mexico | 21.41 |
| Indonesia | 20.78 |
| Nepal | 19.50 |
| Bangladesh | 18.95 |
| Japan | 18.14 |
| Netherlands | 17.50 |
| China | 15.56 |
| Colombia | 15.01 |
| South Korea | 13.22 |
| Myanmar | 12.89 |
| Bolivia | 12.54 |
| Czech Republic | 12.32 |
| Norway | 12.11 |
| Sweden | 12.00 |
| Uruguay | 12.00 |
| Poland | 11.32 |
| Philippines | 11.18 |
| Ireland | 11.00 |
| New Zealand | 11.00 |
| Sri Lanka | 11.00 |
| Taiwan | 11.00 |
| Romania | 10.09 |
| Ecuador | 9.75 |
| United Kingdom | 9.59 |
| Croatia | 9.55 |
| Portugal | 9.51 |
| Greece | 9.00 |
| Slovakia | 8.84 |
| Turkey | 8.76 |
| Papua New Guinea | 8.68 |
| Paraguay | 8.16 |
| Hungary | 8.13 |
| Vietnam | 8.00 |
| Serbia | 7.44 |
| Denmark | 7.34 |
| Finland | 7.09 |
| Ukraine | 7.06 |
| Venezuela | 6.14 |
| Chile | 6.00 |
| Haiti | 5.50 |
| Panama | 5.36 |
| Cambodia | 5.00 |
| Cuba | 4.97 |
| Nicaragua | 4.51 |
| Mongolia | 4.51 |
| North-Macedonia | 4.26 |
| Thailand | 4.01 |
| Latvia | 4.00 |
| Dominican Republic | 3.62 |
| Slovenia | 3.23 |
| El Salvador | 2.09 |
| Albania | 2.00 |
| Bulgaria | 2.00 |
| Lithuania | 2.00 |
| Israel | 2.00 |
| Cyprus | 1.00 |
| Laos | 1.00 |
| Guatemala | 1.00 |
| Honduras | 1.00 |
| Trinidad and Tobago | 0.46 |
| Costa Rica | 0.08 |
| Estonia | 0.00 |
| Iceland | 0.00 |
| Luxembourg | 0.00 |
| Malta | 0.00 |
| Montenegro | 0.00 |
| Kosovo | 0.00 |
| Singapore | 0.00 |
| Brunei | 0.00 |
| East Timor | 0.00 |
| Bhutan | 0.00 |
| Bahamas | 0.00 |
| Barbados | 0.00 |
| Belize | 0.00 |
| Guyana | 0.00 |
| Jamaica | 0.00 |
| Suriname | 0.00 |

Comment: New URL for second link, I assume: https://www.arjanschakel.nl/index.php/regional-authority-index