# Would it be reasonable to see each US "state" as a country in their own, nowadays?

Tags: united-states, statehood

IF there are any difference between an individual US state and an individual country, what are they?

Comment: See: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25759/is-there-a-ranking-of-states-based-on-how-unitary-federalized-they-are. The US isn't even the most federalized state in the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

States cannot

- Make treaties with other states or foreign countries.
- Charge tariffs to other states or foreign countries.
- Violate the federal constitution or federal laws.
- Coin money (of course, some countries can't either, due to treaties).
- Leave the union unilaterally.
- Make war on other states or foreign countries.
- Restrict the privileges and immunities of law-abiding citizens of other states.

From Article I, Section 10 of the [United States constitution](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/constitution-transcript):

> No State shall enter into any Treaty, Alliance, or Confederation; grant Letters of Marque and Reprisal; coin Money; emit Bills of Credit; make any Thing but gold and silver Coin a Tender in Payment of Debts; pass any Bill of Attainder, ex post facto Law, or Law impairing the Obligation of Contracts, or grant any Title of Nobility.
>
> No State shall, without the Consent of the Congress, lay any Imposts or Duties on Imports or Exports, except what may be absolutely necessary for executing it's inspection Laws: and the net Produce of all Duties and Imposts, laid by any State on Imports or Exports, shall be for the Use of the Treasury of the United States; and all such Laws shall be subject to the Revision and Controul of the Congress.
>
> No State shall, without the Consent of Congress, lay any Duty of Tonnage, keep Troops, or Ships of War in time of Peace, enter into any Agreement or Compact with another State, or with a foreign Power, or engage in War, unless actually invaded, or in such imminent Danger as will not admit of delay.

See also Article IV:

> #### Section 1
>
> Full Faith and Credit shall be given in each State to the public Acts, Records, and judicial Proceedings of every other State. And the Congress may by general Laws prescribe the Manner in which such Acts, Records and Proceedings shall be proved, and the Effect thereof.
>
> #### Section 2
>
> 1: The Citizens of each State shall be entitled to all Privileges and Immunities of Citizens in the several States.
>
> 2: A Person charged in any State with Treason, Felony, or other Crime, who shall flee from Justice, and be found in another State, shall on Demand of the executive Authority of the State from which he fled, be delivered up, to be removed to the State having Jurisdiction of the Crime.